# Remove "All Groups" tab from groups page in Buddypress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am using buddypress on my site and i want to hide "All Groups" tab and show only "My Groups" tab to the loggedin user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove "All Groups" Tab in to the loggedin user

Add below function in function.php file

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() )
{
    function hide_all_groups_tab() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
         jQuery("#groups-all").removeClass('selected');
         jQuery('.item-list-tabs ul li:first').css('display', 'none');
         jQuery("#groups-personal").addClass('selected');
    } );
    </script>

    <?php
    }
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'hide_all_groups_tab' );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to change `.item-list-tabs` to `.groups-nav-tabs` but it works like a charm.